# display all elements from array into bootstrap tooltip

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

hello i have an array which i want to show it's elements inside bootstraps tooltip i have the following line of code:

```
<a   style="color:green;"data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{el.ingredientLines[0]}}">{{el.ingredientLines.length}} </a>
```

i need to loopt through whole array instad of picking each elements [0] [1] etc, ng-repeat wont help me because it would repeat el.ingredientLines.lenght as many times as array has elements, so basicly i need this result:
http://prntscr.com/hvhx4g

Answer (score 0):

I think you mix the total number of all items in array (el.ingredientLines.length) with the amount of a particular item. You should introduce new property "amount" or something like that in item.

```
this.el.ingredientLines.push({
  "name": "Dark Chocolate Tafy",
  "amount": 4
});
this.el.ingredientLines.push({
  "name": "Dark Beer...",
  "amount": 6
});
```

and then in view, you would iterate something like this:

```
<a *ngFor="let ingredientLine of el.ingredientLines"  style="color:green;"data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{ingredientLine.name}}">{{ingredientLine.amount}} </a>
```

EDIT:
On the second read, I see your goal is something else. You want to iterate trough item names and list them all in the tooltip.
Then introduce new variable in class:

```
export class xComponent {
   private tooltipOutput: string;
...
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.tooltipOutput = "";
   for (let ingredientLine of el.ingredientLines) {
      this.tooltipOutput += ingredientLine + ", ";
   }
   this.tooltipOutput && (this.tooltipOutput = this.tooltipOutput.slice(0, -2));  // this is to remove final ", "
}
```

and then in view:

```
<a   style="color:green;"data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{tooltipOutput}}">
```

Comment: I noticed at the time that I misunderstood; I corrected my answer, check it out

Comment: this didnt work for me but i simply did this: <a  style="color:green;"data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{el.ingredientLines.toString();}}">number of ingredients: {{el.ingredientLines.length}} </a>

Comment: Cool. If you want to separate that list with something else than comma, for example slash, you can use this: el.ingredientLines.join("/")

Comment: toString function already separated it with , for me it never came to me that i could convert the array to string so its cool and it did the job perfectly